# setUserTrackingMode is slow with annotations on MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, mkannotation

I have MKMapView with annotations. Everything is fine, but if I do this:

```
[_mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
```

rotating using heading is very slow and app slows down whole device.

Any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced exactly the same issue.

Unfortunately I cannot find a solution, therefore I have filed a bug report with Apple.

I think there is a fundamental performance problem with MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading and map annotations.

Comment: I turn this off. Map is static and compass is showing direction to north.

Comment: I have this problem with a lot of annotations. When I create better algorithm using less annotations, `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading` is doing better.

Comment: Have this same issue as well.